# Add Maven properties files to Bamboo directory before maven task

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

I have Maven properties files I don't keep in source control and want to keep on the server for use during the maven task to build the jar. How do I do this in Atlassian's Bamboo?

Comment: You should alway have properties inside your version control and with your build...BTW: What kind of properties?

Comment: Usernames, passwords, tokens, database connection strings, things I don't want in source control.

So, should all of those been parameters I insert on run?

Comment: So for what areas are they needed for the application during the tests ? The connection string shouldn't be problem but of course things like username/password/tokens...You can give a location where to find those files is the simplest solution? Furthermore you can define such things in the settings.xml on the server only...?

Comment: They aren't needed during tests. I need them for the service to start. So you are suggesting I store environment variables for my service in the settings.xml folder used by Maven in Bamboo? I was not even aware that was possible.

Comment: I didn't say you should store environment variables there, cause it's security issue using env variables for things like username/password. You can define properties in the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Properties) file if needed. But if you only need them for starting a service on your Bamboo why not simply using them there...Maybe I misunderstand a thing but why do you need to store them in properties related to Maven ? How do you start your service ?